# Chinese multiple entry Visa in-out options for Pakistan?

Tags: china, pakistani-citizens, hong-kong, taiwan, pakistan

I saw alot of people coming to China with business Visa with M TYPE and after 3 months they go to hongkong or Taiwan and get back with another entry. As for Pakistan it's not free entry to hongkong or Taiwan what are other available options?
Is it possible to get Taiwan or hongkong visa from Shanghai with a Pakistani passport?